# It's possible to listen contract event without knowing contract address?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, addresses, events, web3.py

I have a smart contract with an event where an account address is stored/indexed, and I want to get/advise about this event each time the account address is trigger by the event.

By eg, my solidity event: `myEvent( address indexed _sellerAddress)` where `_sellerAddress` is a personal account address

I want to know/be informed each time my `_sellerAddress` is mentioned is this event, but I don't know at this stage the smart contract address.

let me know if I'm not clear.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found my way by my self.

Just set an `eth.filter` like above with web3.py by e.g :

```
    event_signature_hash = w3.sha3(text='myEvent(address)').hex() #Event name without input arguments

    my_event = w3.eth.filter({
    "fromBlock":0,
    "toBlock":"latest",
    "topics":[event_signature_hash,
    my_seller_address_hexa],
    }
    )
    my_event.get_all_entires()
```

And I got all events logs where `_sellerAddress` is stored/mentioned as event parametre.